# FindBugs and static initialization order

Tags: java, static, initialization, static-analysis, findbugs

I have the following Java code:

```
public class Something {

    static {
        new Something();
    } 

    public static final int[] EMPTY_INT_ARRAY = new int[0];
}
```

I'm using [FindBugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/) to look for code errors, but the following error is never raised:

> SI: Static initializer creates instance before all static final fields
>   assigned (SI_INSTANCE_BEFORE_FINALS_ASSIGNED)
>
> The class's static initializer creates an instance of the class before
>   all of the static final fields are assigned.

Is this the correct case that should demonstrate this issue? why is it not picking up this code issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not tried, but I think an example would be:

```
public class Something {

    static {
        new Something();
    }

    public static final int CONST = 42;
}
```

As lysergic-acid has found out, this error has a lower severity in FindBugs (16). You have to manually lower the min threshold to make it show.

Comment: Silly me, i only pasted part of the class. Sorry. i updated my question with the way it should've been.

Comment: The problem is that this error has a lower severity in FindBugs (16). You have to manually lower the min threshold to make it show. Maybe you can edit your answer to reflect that so i can accept it (so other people may be able to see it if they look for this issue).