# FindBugs: static instance initialization within class

Tags: java, static, findbugs

FindBugs is reporting a bad practice in my code,
[findbugs:SI_INSTANCE_BEFORE_FINALS_ASSIGNED](https://dev.eclipse.org/sonar/coding_rules#qprofile=java-sonar-way-with-findbugs-18979|rule_key=findbugs%3ASI_INSTANCE_BEFORE_FINALS_ASSIGNED|s=createdAt|asc=false).

> The class's static initializer creates an instance of the class before all of the static final fields are assigned.

My code looks something like..

```
public class Foo {

    public static final Foo DEFAULT = new Foo(Bar.A, "baz");

    public enum Bar {
        A, B
    }

    private final Bar bar;
    private final String baz;

    public Foo(Bar bar, String baz) {
        this.bar = bar;
        this.baz = baz;
    }

}
```

I understand it's flagging the use of `new Foo` as a static variable within `Foo` as a bad practice, but don't really see the problem.

Can anyone explain why this is bad practice, what unintended behavior might happen with use of this bad practice, and maybe propose a better practice as an alternative?

Comment: If you look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html), it says : `To provide the same capability for class variables, the Java programming language includes static initialization blocks.` You can use static blocks to instantiate the class.

Comment: @Svasa a static initializer doesn't help. There is already one there, implicitly.

Comment: Are you sure you get that Findbugs message for the posted source? Running your code only gets me a `L P URF_UNREAD_FIELD UrF: Unread field: Foo.baz` warning.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20090807/findbugs-and-static-initialization-order ?

Comment: @Robert, nope, I don't think it's a duplicate. I had read that post before posting my question & it deals with the threshold level required to reveal that warning. It doesn't discuss the meaning of the warning or possible fixes.

My example is almost exactly like my real code, so I think it should give the same FindBugs error. Perhaps refer to the post you linked to regarding lowering your FindBugs threshold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *could* refer to `DEFAULT` in the constructor, or a method called directly or indirectly by the constructor. If you did, its value would be `null`, which may have undesirable consequences for the initialisation of the instance you ultimately assign to `DEFAULT`.

You don't refer to it in this way, so it isn't really a problem here - currently. However, the class could be changed in the future to refer to it accidentally.

In your example code, it looks like a very cheap class to instantiate. You could simply provide a static factory method, `getDefault()`, to create a new instance whenever required. If it is not quite as cheap in reality, you could employ some form of lazy initialization.

Comment: That's a really good point, I _could_ reference the static from the constructor. Surprised it doesn't give some infinite recursion loop. Thanks Andy!